# vb.net CefSharp.Windows document.getElementById

Tags: cefsharp

We used webbrowser control to login website in VB.NET, now we are going to us CefSharp.
We have made a simple test form. Clicking on the button sets the "toegangscode". It works, but when I go to next field wachtwoord (password) and type 1 first character the "toegangscode" field will be made empty. What I am doing wrong ?

Public Class Form1

```
Public WithEvents browser As ChromiumWebBrowser

Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    Dim settings As New CefSharp.WinForms.CefSettings()
    CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings)

    browser = New CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("https://diensten.kvk.nl/inloggen.html") With {
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill}
    Panel1.Controls.Add(browser)

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim jsScript1 = <js><![CDATA[document.getElementById("username").focus();]]></js>.Value
    browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(jsScript1)


    Dim jsScript2 As String = <js><![CDATA[document.getElementById("username").value = "xxxxxx";]]></js>.Value
    browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(jsScript2)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim bCanExecuteJavascriptInMainFrame As Boolean = browser.CanExecuteJavascriptInMainFrame

    Dim bIsBrowserInitialized As Boolean = browser.IsBrowserInitialized

    If bIsBrowserInitialized Then
        browser.ShowDevTools()
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: First step in debugging is to open DevTools and confirm that your JavaScript works correctly. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging

Comment: I have mad a new button on the form. DevTools opens and both booleans CanExecuteJavascriptInMainFrame and IsBrowserInitialized are TRUE.

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim bCanExecuteJavascriptInMainFrame As Boolean = browser.CanExecuteJavascriptInMainFrame

        Dim bIsBrowserInitialized As Boolean = browser.IsBrowserInitialized

        If bIsBrowserInitialized Then
            browser.ShowDevTools()
        End If

Comment: Please edit your original question and add the code there, it's unreadable in the comments. Did your JavaScript run correctly when executed in DevTools console? Was the form updated as expected?

Comment: JavaScript runs as expected, input field with id = username is filled with xxxxxx

Comment: What happens when you click button1 exactly? Check the DevTools console for errors.